# Acquiring a country's currency code

Tags: java, android, location, locale, currency

I have a problem getting a country's currency code. My task is to get the user's location, find out what country he is right now and get this country's currency code. Here's the code that fetches the country name and country code from the acquired location:

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(
                location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 5);

textView1.setText(addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
textView2.setText(addresses.get(0).getCountryCode());
```

This works perfectly fine. Now I should use the `java.util.Currency` class to get a `Currency` object. I can use the `Currency.getInstance(Locale locale)` method. But there's no constructor in the `Locale` class that allows only the country code to be passed as an argument. Means I am not able to create a `Locale` object for the country. How can this be solved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a constructor `Locale(String language, String country)` that conforms to `ISO-639` language groups.

Comment: Locale(String language, String country) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `Currency.getInstance(new Locale("",code))`, with a possible Exception if the country code isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
String lang = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
Locale locale = new Locale(lang, COUNTRY_YOU_HAVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not you use Address object to get Locale, by method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getLocale%28%29

Comment: You shouldn't do that since `getLocale()` returns the system default `Locale` which was passed to the `Geocoder` instance, so it will always return the device default country.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the result of doing this will be inaccurate since we don't have the `Language Code`, or it can even throw an exception due to not having that `Locale` on the system.
Instead I'd search for it doing the following:

```
val locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales().first { it.country == address.countryCode }
val currency = Currency.getInstance(locale)
```

Also, if you want to try to be as accurate as possible, you could do this:

```
val locale =
    Locale.getAvailableLocales().firstOrNull { it.country.equals(countryCode, true) && it.language.equals(countryCode, true) }
        ?: Locale.getAvailableLocales().firstOrNull { it.country.equals(countryCode, true) }
        ?: Locale.getDefault()
val currency = Currency.getInstance(locale)
```